# Getting emacs to convert latex on the fly?

Tags: configuration, emacs, latex

What's really nice about posting in the math stackexchange, and other forums, is that you can view the latex symbols right below as you're typing your post. Is there a way to do this in emacs? That is, can I type "$\in$" and have it immediately convert the code to the "element of" symbol (in the position where I typed it)?

Answer (score 7):

[AucTEX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) includes [preview-latex-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/preview-latex.html), which almost does what you want.  (I don't think it autoconverts by default, but I'm confident you could configure it to do so.)

Answer (score 1):

you can preview-latex-mode use only in syntatic correct LaTeX files.

however there are two other solutions
1. org-preview-latex-fragment: which works with the same idea (subs latex by png) but you can do it in ANY buffer, email etc.

1. you can also use x-symbol which uses fonts to display $\int$ as an integral.
   Again it works in ANY buffer.
   I am not sure that x-symbol still works with recent GNU emacs 24 but I do know it 
   works for Xemacs.